# Trying to let my lambda access an RDS database (postgres) but when creating database proxy the "RDS DB Instance" is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I created an RDS postgres database with public access. I can connect to it from SQL Workbench and perform SQL queries. Now I want to build a lambda to query data from my database.

Following the instructions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-database.html

In this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbANf.jpg

If I open the "RDS DB instance" drop down my database is not there.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you were getting the issue?

Answer (score 4):

A common reason for that is using **wrong PostgreSQL version**. RDS proxy supports only [some version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy.limitations):

> For RDS PostgreSQL, RDS Proxy supports version 10.10 and higher minor versions, and version 11.5 and higher minor versions. For Aurora PostgreSQL, RDS Proxy supports version 10.11 and higher minor versions, and 11.6 and higher minor versions.

Thus, if you use newest version PostgreSQL 12, RDS proxy will not show it as its **not supported**.

You still can use this db from lambda, but have to associate your function with the **VPC** where RDS is and setup security groups so that function can connect to the db.

Comment: ahh i missed those details. i thought it might be because of the region (I'm in Singapore), but turns actually it is the version. now i can see it populate my database if i create a postgres on version 11.5. thanks :)

Unfortunately, I've now got stuck at a new problem. same screen. i want to use the secret manager for uname and pw, so I do and I can select my created secret. But when I create an IAM policy and then attach it to a new role, I cannot see my role populated in the IAM role box. The only roles I can see are AWSServiceRoleForRDS and rds-monitoring-role. I am really stumped.

Comment: @Prof I would suggest to make new question with the details of the relevant roles. Its difficult to infer just from comments what could be happening.